# Magento 2.2 data migration Duplicate store_group_name Entries

Tags: database, magento2.2, data-migration

I am trying to migrate a store from 1.9.2.2 to Magento 2.2 using the Magento data migration tool but unfortunately when running the tool the error appears

> [PDOException]
>       SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'default' for key 'STORE_GROUP_CODE'

As I understand

`STORE_GROUP_CODE` is a new column added in Magento 2.2 
It is generated from column `STORE_GROUP_NAME` which in Magento 2.X is found in table STORE_GROUP

In Magento 1.9.2.2 column `STORE_GROUP_NAME` is located with table `CORE_STORE_GROUP`

from within the Magento 1.9.2.2 database

[image]

so migration is failing because of the duplicate entries.

The default Value for website_id 0 (admin) should be 'default'
The default value for website id 1 (base) should be 'Main Website Store'

Unfortunately, both my store_group_names are the default.

As an experiment I change `Store_Group_Name` for website 1 (base) to 'Main Website Store' and data migration ran no problems.

Everything worked until I reindex the result was

Frontend: When viewing the store (on a clean luma 2.2 installations) the add to cart buttons are missing 
Backend: All products show in list view but if you click one product it loads with the error: Unable to unserialize value

Does anyone know how I can change the Store_Group_Name website id 1 (base) without breaking the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution was just to change store name in magento admin  of 1.9.2.2 then export

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 has new field `'code'` in `store_group` table and it is automatically created from magento 1 store name.So it seems you have a duplicate store name in magento 1

First try to make the store name unique in magento 1 from **`system > Manage stores`** and then **run migration setting command.**

Comment: Nice Explanation!!